# Error convirtiendo a fecha corta VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Soy nuevo en VBA, estoy automatizando la generación de reportes, importo los datos de un archivo .txt a excel, pero las fechas de una columna no cambian al formato de fecha corta, al principio copiaba y pegaba la información por lo que ahora importo los datos pero me sigo enfrentando al mismo error.

Adjunto el código de mi trabajo:

```
Sub para_Importar_()
Dim mPath, iFile$, ws As Worksheet

mPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Archivos de texto (*.txt),*.txt)")
If VarType(mPath) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
mPath = Left(mPath, InStrRev(mPath, "\"))
iFile = Dir(mPath & "*.txt")
Set ws = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Sheets(1)

Do Until iFile = ""
  ws.Parent.Worksheets.Add after:=ws.Parent.Worksheets(ws.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
  ActiveSheet.Name = iFile

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & _
    mPath & iFile, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True: .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True: .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False: .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ".": .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With


With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
.TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
   .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
   '.NumberFormat = "@"
  .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With
```

Un ejemplo de la columna E es:

```
04/10/2019
04-10-2019 50:49:00
04/10/2019
04/10/2019
```

Ya no de que otra forma modificar el código para que cambie el formato de fecha como debe, también intente poner en la línea de Query Table el formato de texto que ocupo en esas dos columnas que es xlDMYFormat pero no funciona.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
With ActiveSheet
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = .UsedRange.Value
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'empezamos por la fila 2 ya que supongo que la fila 1 tiene encabezados
            arr(i, 4) = arr(i, 4) * 1 'con esto multiplicas el valor de la celda por 1 y se convierte en valor. Dará fallo si alguna celda es texto de verdad.
            arr(i, 5) = arr(i, 5) * 1
            If IsNumeric(arr(i, 5)) Then
             ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
            End If
        Next i
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Haz un bucle y arregla cada fecha individualmente. ¿Has probado?

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, no lo he probado, apreciaría un poco de ayuda para realizar el bucle, estoy algo bloqueado :/ @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Comment: @Zerrets tu problema 100% es que estás importando esos campos como texto, así que excel no te los formatea porque para él son un texto. Lo mejor sería pasarlos a numero. Dime qué columnas son las que son de fechas y te pongo un ejemplo para que te las convierta.

Comment: Columna D y Columna E @Damian

Comment: @Damian Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo intentaré en un rato que tenga el otro ordenador, me has ayudado bastante con esa solución, estaba desesperado.

Comment: @Damian Me marcó error en la columna E como indicaste de que el valor de la celda es texto de verdad ¿ Cómo puedo solucionarlo ?

Comment: @Damian Grabé la macro para las celdas que no cambian la fecha y de esta manera puedo lograr cambiarlas al formato que deseo ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: @Damian añadí el pedazo de código a la pregunta

Comment: @Damian Cómo puedo arreglar la condición para el error en el array(i,5) ?

Comment: @Damian Por dónde te puedo mandar el archivo ? y otra pregunta, al posicionarme sobre la celda me sigue apareciendo hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Damian listo, ya adjunté el link

Comment: @Damian muchas gracias, te agradezco tu tiempo para ayudarme a resolver este problema que he tenido, sólo tengo una pequeña duda, al posicionarme sobre las celdas me siguen apareciendo las horas, minutos y segundos, tengo entendido que DateValue remueve las horas, minutos y segundos permanentemente de las celdas.

Comment: @Damian No, sólo quiero dd/mm/yyyy pero al posicionarme sobre tal celda en la barra de fórmulas me sigue apareciendo dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, sólo quiero que tanto en la celda como en la barra de fórmulas me aparezca sólo dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @Damian Gracias, en unas horas sí aplica y en otras no aplica, tengo duda de por qué.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```
Option Explicit
Sub para_Importar_()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim mPath As String: mPath = GetFolder
    mPath = mPath & "\"

    Dim iFile As String
    iFile = Dir(mPath & "*.txt")

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Do While iFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        ws.Name = iFile

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & _
            mPath & iFile, Destination:=ws.Range("$A$1"))
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True: .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False: .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False: .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ".": .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        'Do the first parse
        If ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count = 1 Then _
            ws.UsedRange.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
              DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              Tab:=False, _
              Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, _
              Space:=False, _
              other:=True, _
              OtherChar:="|", _
              FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, xlDMYFormat))
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = ws.UsedRange.Value
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            arr(i, 4) = FechaConSinHora(arr(i, 4))
            arr(i, 5) = FechaConSinHora(arr(i, 5))
        Next i
        ws.UsedRange.Value = arr
        ws.Range("D:E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

        iFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Private Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Elige una carpeta"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
Private Function FechaConSinHora(arr As Variant) As Date
      FechaConSinHora = CDate(Left(arr, 10))
End Function
```

Lo complicado ha sido encontrar el patrón de separación de tus datos, y al final era el carácter "|", una vez solucionado eso ya he podido tratar bien los archivos.

He utilizado 2 funciones auxiliares:

- La primera te va a permitir seleccionar 
  Una carpeta entera en la que puedes tener 1, 100, 2000 archivos, que si son .txt los leerá y tratará todos.
- La segunda se encarga de leer las fechas, si las lee como número o fecha, las formatea como fecha, si por el contrario las lee como texto (hay algunas fechas como 01/10/2019 52:41:12 que no tiene sentido) eliminará la parte de las "horas" quedándose únicamente con la fecha.

Comment: Efectivamente, en el array con la fila 5 me marca error porque es texto de verdad ¿ Cómo puedo enfrentrarme a ese problema ?

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
    Range("L3").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Comment: @Zerrets pon delante de las conversiones `If IsNumeric(arr(i, 4)) Then ...`

Comment: Iría después de arr(i,5) = arr(i,5) * 1 ? @Damian

Comment: @Zerrets he editado el código para que veas cómo quedaría con el condicional.

Comment: Las fechas siguen sin cambiarse :| gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Zerrets sería posible que me pasaras un txt de prueba para probar yo?

Comment: Sí, sólo que no puedo abrir el debate en el chat

Comment: @Zerrets sube el archivo a un drive, dropbox o lo que sea y dame el link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEcjg3g0TXFtllXmRUGdBYiqQcxI4ErX/view?usp=drivesdk @Damian

Comment: @Zerrets pues ya estaría, con este código que he dejado en mi respuesta he sido capaz de tratar todos los archivos en la carpeta ficheros.

Comment: muchas gracias, te agradezco tu tiempo para ayudarme a resolver este problema que he tenido, sólo tengo una pequeña duda, al posicionarme sobre las celdas me siguen apareciendo las horas, minutos y segundos, tengo entendido que DateValue remueve las horas, minutos y segundos permanentemente de las celdas.

Comment: No sabía si querías las horas, si es así, en la función de `FechaConSinHora` borra todo y deja sólo esto: `FechaConSinHora = CDate(Left(arr, 10))`

Comment: No, sólo quiero dd/mm/yyyy pero al posicionarme sobre tal celda en la barra de fórmulas me sigue apareciendo dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, sólo quiero que tanto en la celda como en la barra de fórmulas me aparezca sólo dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Por eso, haz lo que te he dicho en mi comentario anterior y desaparecerán las horas.

Comment: Gracias, en unas horas sí aplica y en otras no aplica, tengo duda de por qué.